# Should a statistical test be performed if power is very low?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, fishers-exact-test, bioinformatics

I performed some partitioning of data set (genes) into two lists, resulting in two enrichment lists. I wanted to compare them with Fisher's test, but from before I know that similarly looking results can have low power.  Thus I calculated power first and it is below 0.3 or even below 0.1 for most comparisons (I have in fact different clusterings).

Should I even try to run Fisher's test in such case? Are there any better ways to determine if clusters are biologically different based on enrichment analysis?

Furthermore, I have a contingency table based on both absent, both present etc. Do you think that it would be ok to include as "whole" the compared partitions + enrichment of un-partitioned dataset so that I even get some counts in "both absent" cell?

Comment: Like playing a game, if you have 10% chance of wining, you still want to give a try, then do it. If you think the risk is too high, then give up.

Comment: Could you please say more about the goal of your study, the nature of your data, how you partitioned your genes into 2 lists, and how you plan to use Fisher's test to analyze your data? That might help with an answer to your question about "better ways to determine if clusters are biologically different based on enrichment analysis."

Comment: The genes were partitioned in two lists by clustering, so I  want to see if the similarity scores used for clustering can generate sensible groups of genes - eg. actually having different biological roles. Fishers test would be performed on counts of pathways enriched at q-value threshold of 0.25, with all pathways from the two compared clusters+unpartitioned list's enrichment as background.

Comment: It was decided that there would be no point in performing Fisher's test as I know from similar data generated previously (on different clustering) that such low power will lead to false negatives even when the lists are obviously different - e.g. most of the pathways are not shared. But now the situation is more tricky as the difference is not so striking, but power is still too low.